# Half of a uniform disc suspended by two strings

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, statics

Suppose we have a half of a thin, homogenous disc hanging from the ceiling as shown:
[image]

Given the weight of the disc $Q$, calculate tensions in strings $S_1$,$S_2$. Now this seemed like quite a simple problem but somehow it turned out to puzzle me. It is obvious that $F_1+F_2=Q$ ( here $F_1$, $F_2$ and $Q$ represent magnitudes of respective vectors). Using torque came to mind, but i haven;t got any information about the disk, much less it's radius, center of mass, nor string lengths.. Logic tells me these forces should be equal but I just can't seem to put that to paper. Since this body is in equilibrium, it's only logical to assume $F_1$ = $F_2$, but then again, gravity too will tend to rotate the body about it's center of mass.

Comment: MIght want to look at the torque about each connection point as well.

Answer (score 1):

If it's uniform, you can easily find the center of mass.

If it's in equilibrium, you know that the sum of torques *about any point* must be zero.  Choose your point for convenience. From that you can easily put torques in terms of an unknown radius, $S_1, S_2,$ and Q.

If you know the weight and assume a gravitational field strength $g$, then you know the mass.

The rest is algebra.  I haven't worked the details, but I suspect that the radius will disappear